# Why is the decay of the positive Kaon into two Pion more likely than decay of the positive Kaon into three Pion?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction

I was wondering if someone could explain me (or introduce me a reference) about my following question:

Why is the decay of the positive Kaon into two Pion more likely than decay of the positive Kaon into three Pion?

Comment: are you aware of the mass of the pion and the mass of the kaon?

Comment: @annav Yes, I know. The mass of the koan is $493.7Mev/c^2$ and the mass of a Pion is $139.6Mev/c^2$.

Comment: @annav I would really appreciate if you could help me about my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the tree diagrams for the decay? The 2 decay involves emission of a W⁺ while the 3 decay requires emission of a W⁺ then also a gluon. The requirement for a second emission process reduces the probability.

Comment: @JohnRennie - surely an answer and you need the reputations?!

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes, I have checked the Fynmann diagram. But could you please tell me why "The requirement for a second emissions process reduces probability?"

Comment: @Farcher Could you please tell me why "The requirement for a second emissions process reduces probability?"

Comment: @Mahtab  qualitatively  I meant that to start with, the mass of the kaon is about 500 mev/c^2 and each pion will remove a large number of the energy for the rest  of the particles needed to balance quantum numbers etc.Three pions leave only about 50 mev/c^2 , and as the other comments state, the quantum mechanical probabilities will be very small the more pions produced.